# Calculate the correlation function of $n^{\prime}(t)=\int_{0}^{T} k(t, \tau) n(\tau) d \tau$

Tags: integration, signal-processing

Let us consider the following signal:
$$n^{\prime}(t)=\int_{0}^{T} k(t, \tau) n(\tau) d \tau$$
prove that the correlation function is
$$R_{n^\prime}(t, s)=\int_{0}^{T} \int_{0}^{T} k(t, \tau) k^{*}(s, u) R_{n}(\tau, u)d\tau du$$
It is the equation (6.33) of the following [report](https://apps.dtic.mil/sti/pdfs/AD0609978.pdf) (page 104). I can't figure out how to come up with this expression. I tried with $R_{n^\prime}(s)=\int_{\mathbb R} \left(n^{\prime}(t)\right)^* n^{\prime}(t+s) dt$ but I can't get an expression in t and s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempted solution does not use the correct formula for the correlation function of a stochastic process (time-series), which is
$$
R_x(t,s)=E[x(t)x(s)^*]
$$
Substituting $x(t)=n'(t)=\int_0^T k(t,\tau)n(\tau)d\tau$ into the above and using the linearity of the expectation operator gives the desired result:
$$
R_n'(t,s)=E\left[\left(\int_0^T k(t,a)n(a)da\right)\cdot 
\left(\int_0^T k(s,b)^*n(b)^* db\right)\right]=
$$
$$
\iint_{[0,T]^2} k(t,a)k(s,b)^*R_n(a,b) \, da\,db
$$